# Can anyone explain the ember.js create function

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am having trouble understanding the code below which is from ember.js and is used to create an instance of an ember object:

```
  var K = function() {};

  Ember.create = function(obj, props) {
    K.prototype = obj;
    obj = new K();
    if (props) {
      K.prototype = obj;
      for (var prop in props) {
        K.prototype[prop] = props[prop].value;
      }
      obj = new K();
    }
    K.prototype = null;

    return obj;
  };
```

I don't get why K gets set to the prototype of the obj argument and then why new is called again.

I don't understand why these lines appear more than once:

```
K.prototype = new K();
```

and

```
obj = new K()
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this function there is a bug, because this function uses for IE8-([source](http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.5.0/ember.js)) and in source `Ember.create` is equal for [`Object.create`](http://caniuse.com/#search=Object.create) for all other browsers. Let's try to explain:

```
  var K = function() {};//base class (with empty constructor)

  //inheritance function, create essence from obj with props
  Ember.create = function(obj, props) {
    K.prototype = obj;//classical inheritance from obj
    obj = new K();//use obj instead of new var, create new essence
    if (props) {//has methods
      K.prototype = obj;//seams like a bug? Means obj from arguments, but get as new K()
      for (var prop in props) {
        K.prototype[prop] = props[prop].value;
      }
      obj = new K();//create essence with props (just create it again)
    }
    K.prototype = null;//reset methods, props 

    return obj;//return new essence
  };
```

I think the author means something like this:

```
var stdClass = function() {};

Ember.create = function(proto, props) {
    var createdEssence;

    stdClass.prototype = proto;

    if (props) {
        for (var prop in props) {
            stdClass.prototype[prop] = props[prop].value;
        }
    }

    createdEssence = new stdClass();

    stdClass.prototype = null;

    return createdEssence;
};
```